# why a rewrite_rule works only when the folder exist?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ovh

**The objective** is to input an url like

```
https://www.mywebsite/expert/188/name-of-the-expert
```

and return it to the server in the form

```
expert.php?exp=188
```

Like if the user typed in `https://www.mywebsite/expert.php?exp=188`

**WHAT DOES NOT WORK:**
simple rules like RewriteRule `^expert-([0-9]*)$ expert.php?exp=$1 [L,NC,QSA]`

**WHAT WORK**
I have the following rewrite_rule that works only when I **physically** create the folder expert/ in my tree, i.e. /www/expert/

```
# FRIENDLY URL FOR EXPERTS PROFILE
Rewriterule ^(.*)expert\/([0-9]*)(\/[a-z0-9\-\']*)?\/?$ expert.php?exp=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Also, for this rule to work, I had to put the `<base href="/">` in the page expert.php to avoid errors with all my linked resources:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

The server is APACHE on a shared web hosting platform named OVH.

The full code of the issue:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /

# FRIENDLY URL FOR EXPERTS PROFILE
Rewriterule ^(.*)expert\/([0-9]*)(\/[a-z0-9\-\']*)?\/?$ expert.php?exp=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it like this with `MultiViews` turned off:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# FRIENDLY URL FOR EXPERTS PROFILE
Rewriterule ^/?expert/(\d+)/?$ expert.php?exp=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Option `MultiViews` (see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html) is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs **before** `mod_rewrite` and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So if `/file` is the URL then Apache will serve `/file.html`.

Comment: It works perfectly but I need to keep the first back-reference (.*) for it to work. and the html `base tag`. Any idea why ?

Comment: `base` tag is needed because you're relative paths for css/js/images

Answer (score 1):

I changed from using rewrite rules to using Apaches FallbackResource after reading https://www.adayinthelifeof.nl/2012/01/21/apaches-fallbackresource-your-new-htaccess-command/.  It's more of a 'if page not found, then run this page instead'

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
    FallbackResource /root.php
</Directory>
```

The only thing I have found is that if the URL is for page that does exist - then it serves that instead of your base new base page 'root.php' in my case.

Comment: interesting but I do not need a fallback, I need to go to the desired page expert.php?exp=188

Comment: The way I've used it is that expert.php page becomes your fallback.  I've written a nano REST framework which uses this idea, for me the main entry point is the root.php page.

Comment: I will try but I may have troubles if i create the expert folder in the future and I want another fallback. Can you apply your answer based on my question because I'm not sure how to implement it.